# Silverlight, WPF. How to determine is one control located over other?

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, controls

What is the best solution to check is one control located over other.

For example, I have two TextBoxes and when one TextBox is over the other I need to hide one of them.

AND i need to determine is this cotnrols overlaped before i will add them to visul tree!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean you want to find out if they overlap in the Z-dimension?

Untested:

```
// requires System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll

using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
// ...

Rect? rect1 = myControl1.GetBoundsRelativeTo(someParentContainer);
Rect? rect2 = myControl2.GetBoundsRelativeTo(someParentContainer);

bool areIntersecting = rect1 != null && rect2 != null
    && rect1.Value.Intersect(rect2.Value) != Rect.Empty;
```

Comment: Thanks, for reply. Yes this is what i am looking for. But i cannot use any Toolkits, just such requirment. Is in clear WPF i can find something like that?

Comment: @Evgeny, the toolkit is open source, you'll find the implementation for `GetBoundsRelativeTo(...)` here: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/56962#779713

Comment: I have exception: The specified Visual and this Visual do not share a common ancestor, so there is no valid transformation between the two Visuals.

Comment: I need to check is they overlaped before i will add them to visual tree

Comment: @Evgeny, yes this method can only work once the controls have been added to the visual tree and the layout is final. Normally it isn't a problem to remove your other textbox by then, it's fast enough for the user. ;-) ... If you really, really have to check before, it's much more effort. You'll have to build a layout in memory beforehand. You'll have to explicitly set Width, Height and positions for each of your controls. You can then use these values to build your own `Rect` instances und use the above method to check if anything intersects.

Comment: Thanks, i will see what can i do.

Answer (score -1):

If you're after a tool rather than a programmatic solution, [snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) does this for WPF apps.  It shows you a hierarchical view of the composition of controls in your app at runtime.

Never used it, but [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/) seems to be a Silverlight equivalent.

Comment: Ah, I see you edited the question.  It is clear that you do want it programmatically.  Oh well.